# How to delete a commit permanently from a local repo? (so that it is no longer accessible using "git reset --hard <hash>"

Tags: git

I did some tests on a repository with two commits. Either of these will set the head to the first commit and ensure that the second doesn't display when I do "git log".

Alernative 1:
`git reset --hard [commit 1 hash]`

Alternative 2:

`git rebase --onto master~1 master~0 master`

However if I try this:

`git reset --hard [commit 2 hash]`

The HEAD is back at commit 2 (which is proof that it was never deleted). How to really delete it permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git gc` should do the trick. By default it will prune unreachable commits older than 2 weeks; you can use `--prune=<date>` to override this.

Run `git help gc` for details on what will and will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks. On its own, "git gc --prune=now" doesn't do the trick though. Had to use two commands.
"git reflog expire --all --expire=now"
and "git gc --prune=now"

And now the second commit is gone.("unknown revision or path not in the working tree")